# How to load HTML file into HTML use JS with button

Tags: javascript, html, function, button

I what to load the b.js file to HTML with button and function. when user type "yes" and click on "Ok" button, "b.js" must load in page (not open in new window or new tab)

what code I must to use in ??????????? place to solve my problem?
here is the code:

HOME.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form name="load">yes OR no<input name="id" type="text">
<input type="button" value="OK" onClick="my(document.forms.load)">
<script>
function my(form) {
    if (form.id.value=="yes") {              

?????????????
   
        } else {
            alert("NO")
        }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

b.js

```
document.write(`

<html>
<h1> Load the HTML code</h1>
</html>

`);
```

---

I tried to use  `<script src="b.js"></script>` but this code immediately load "b.js" that I dont what this

I tried to use

```
var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
scriptTag.setAttribute('src','b.js');
document.head.appendChild(scriptTag)
```

but not working

I tried to use

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML += "<script src='b.js'></script>";
```

but this code not working

what can I do to load the "b.js" file after click on button?

thanks :)

Comment: Why would you want to do this? `b.js` is tiny. Just load it in with the original page. It sounds like you're making things very complicated.

Comment: @Andy this is for test in here. the original is more than 1260 line code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking gor?

```js
function my(form) {
  const loadHTML = () => {
    const scriptB = document.createElement('script')
    scriptB.setAttribute('src','b.js')
    console.log(scriptB)
    document.write(`
      <h1>Load the HTML code</h1>
      ${scriptB.outerHTML}
    `);
  }
  if (form.id.value==="yes") {
    loadHTML()
  } else {
    alert("NO")
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form name="load">
  <h2>YES or NO</h2>
  <input name="id" type="text">
  <input type="button" value="OK" onClick="my(document.forms.load)">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you just want to append the script "b.js" after button click?